# update many line with sqlite

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I use Phonegap
I want to change multiple lines on the same table using sqlite.
i use this code, but not work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < id_input_type_cotation.length ; i++)
    {
var sql ="UPDATE Selectionner  SET QuotationParDefaut = '?'  WHERE  (IdPrestation = '3') and (IdPhrase = "+id_input_type_cotation[i]+") ; ";

params = [ id_input_type_cotation[i] ];
tx_commenter.executeSql(sql, params);
console.log("I= "+i);

    }
```

Comment: difficult to say without further details. what error do you get ?

Comment: have you any other solution :(

Comment: After the "params=" line can you add console.log(sql); and tell what the output in the console log is ?